# How to increase the thread pool for the fix transport

Tags: wso2-esb

I'm trying to use the fix transport while inserting some data into a database using a dbreport mediator, the fix transport apparently is limited by default to 10 threads in the pool.

If I want to increase this, what do I need to do?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Currently wso2 esb uses its mediation engine as Synapses and the fix transport code in the synapse is available in [WSO2 github repository](https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/blob/master/modules/transports/optional/fix/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/transport/fix/FIXTransportSender.java).

Current implementation does not allow to change the number of thread in the thread pool. Therefore, you might have to change the code and build by WSO2 ESB by your self.